# Is it possible to see what a question looked like after the nth revision?

Tags: support, questions, revisions-list

I wonder if it is possible to see specific previous versions of questions, i.e. the way they looked back when they were edited n times.

The revision history gives a good idea, but they're all diffs, so sometimes a version looks like this (actual screenshot):

[image: lots of red and green]

and it's not clear what it really would have looked like on the page.
You can click on "source", which gives a reasonable rough draft, but I want to see the result.

Not proposing this as a feature request, since I don't feel it's important enough for the programmers to spend time on; I just wonder if it's at all possible now.

Edit:
As Martin Smith [points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140078/is-it-possible-to-see-what-a-question-looked-like-after-the-nth-revision#comment395169_140078), you can click on "Edit" next to "Source" on sites where you have edit privileges. So that's that part taken care of, but how about sites where you don't?

Comment: Did you mean, **before** the nth Revision ?

Comment: If you have edit priveliges you can click the "edit" link in the revision history to open up the specific revision in the editor. Sometimes makes things clearer.

Comment: @Lucifer That depends on how you count. The edit history counts versions, not revisions, so number 1 is the original and number 2 is the first revision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you click on the link icon (<sub>[image: link icon]</sub>) next to the revision, it will take you to a direct page for that specific revision. That page lacks the controls which let you see what changed, but it will show you [the end result of that edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/140040/2).